# Wait for loop to finish server call before running to next statement in android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a requirement where there is a dynamic form with different types like take edittext, upload image etc.

The issue I am facing is while iterating thru all cases I have to upload image to server and get that url before moving to next type. And at last post form data to server.

I tried putting all code in thread:

```
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
          @Override
        public void run() {
           //Code below with for loop
        }
        }).start();
```

Also upload image is in asnctask

```
   for (int fieldIndex = 0; fieldIndex < section.getFields().size(); fieldIndex++) {
    switch (field.getType()) {
                case ("TextField"):
                 //take data
                 break;
                case ("Number"):
                    //take data
                 break;
                   case ("image"):
                    // UPLOAD to server and get that url in Asynctask
                    break;
        } fieldIndex++;
    }
      // Once for loop done upload all data witb image url to server
```

But it's not waiting for image URL but iterating the loop and if its not incremented, then upload image function call again.

Comment: implement a recall which is called when your upload finishes and which updates only the specified items which Need the URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first find image from list and upload to server, after successful upload response save image url.
Then get all data using for loop and upload all data to server with image url.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a Thread, you can delay the iteration so it can wait in a sense using:

```
Thread.sleep("2000");
```

Or you can use:

```
 SystemClock.sleep("2000");
```

which is a similar function but ignores the InterruptedException

Comment: I have shared only one case of one image, other type of form can have array of image to upload so I dont think Sleep will be good idea. Thanks for taking time to replay.

Answer (score 0):

Use RXAndroid/RXKotlin, its the perfect solution for your usecase, as tasks are dependent on each other.

Comment: Can you please specify what in RXAndroid can help? I havent use RX so that will help. Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: Don't use loop for server calls, Go through basics of RX. refer following code,                                           
  private fun getObserver(): Observer<String> {
      return object : Observer<String> {
          override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {
          }
          override fun onNext(s: String) {
               }
           override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
               }
 
//When onComplete is called, print the following to Logcat//
           override fun onComplete() {
               }
      }
  }